# Read a file with php on php hosting

Tags: php, hosting, readfile

I am trying to read a file (ex: pdf file) on php hosting.

My code:

```
$myarray = array(); 
$path = "/home/mywebsite.com/httpdocs"; 
$open = opendir($path);

while ($x = readdir($open)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $myarray[] = $file;
    }
}

sort($myarray);
closedir($open);

echo json_encode($myarray);
```

This code is running but if I change the value of $path :    "/home/mywebsite.com/mydirectory/" instead of  "/home/mywebsite.com/httpdocs", this code does not run.

I want to store my documents in my directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the script have proper permissions to view the directory `/home/mywebsite.com/mydirectory`? (i.e. the `chmod` permission value is something like `0755`)

Comment: May be your PHP interpreter cannot reach anything than your httpdocs directory for security reasons. You may put your files inside your document root, protecting the directory from direct HTTP access using a .htaccess file, for example.

Comment: ok. I did as you said . thanks